# Why am I getting occasional maxed out values?

Tags: arduino

I have a accelerometer hooked up to wemos d1 mini, when I try to calculate the magnitude, there is occasional 2^31.
What causes this and how can I fix it?
Thank you!

```
  int avgAcX = totalAcX/count;
  int avgAcY = totalAcY/count;
  int avgAcZ = totalAcZ/count;
  int oldAvgAcXYZ = sqrt(avgAcX*avgAcX + avgAcY*avgAcY + avgAcZ*avgAcZ);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAw56.png)

Comment: In some cases, in your sqrt expression, you are multiplying two values that are each > 2^16, so your products are overflowing. You may need to scal them down or make them float before multiplying.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the results are correct? They are way too small for that values

And I can see from the spot it can't fit into the int32_t type:

```
hex(17510*17510 + 64370*64370 + 58803*58803) = 0x1D758D291  (int32_t = 0xD758D291 which is negative)
   correct value: 88926

hex(17510*17510 + 64370*64370 + 65803*65803) = 0x20B562DE1  (int32_t = 0x0B562DE1 eg positive)
   correct value: 93702  (yours are around 11000)
```

And because sqrt is defined only for positive numbers and zero, it returns NaN float value, casted to int32...

Comment: How did I not see this... I just divide the values by 10, and although it looses some resolution, its good enough and is fixed cheers